# Enabling EF6 database migrations on existing databases

Tags: entity-framework-6, data-migration, entity-framework-migrations

I have an app and it has a database behind it. This app is deployed in multiple instances, where each instance has different version of code and database. By different version, I mean it might be slightly older version of code and database.

What I would like to do is:

1. Start using EF6 database migrations on the development version.
2. In correct order (dev->stage->prod), deploy to other instances the development version and update the database using EF6 database migrations.
3. Create new instance of app, using EF6 database migrations.

The question I am running into is this:

I understand that I can enable migrations on my development instance, then do Add-Migration Initial –IgnoreChanges and create incremental migrations for new database changes. As other environments will be updated, these changes will be applied (running Update-Database during deployment).

However, my question is, with this kind of setup, how to handle when I have to spin up a new instance of the app? I need a migration which would create all the tables. I know how to create this migration also: by pointing the connecting string to empty database and running Add-Migration. However, when I will deploy my code to existing instances and run Update-Database, EF will try to run this baseline migration and crash.

How to handle these two scenarios in a simple and automated way?

I guess I am imagining two types of migrations:

- **Update-Database -Baseline-And-Incremental**

and

- **Update-Database -Incremental**

Also, this will all be automated, so I dont want to run Update-Database and pass in the non-baseline migration names to run on existing database during deployment.

Answer (score 0):

1st

In your DbContext constructor add

```
Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<MPContext>()); //Create database if not existed
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<yourContext, Configuration>()); // uses the configuration for migrations for this DbContext
```

and your configuration class should look like this:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<DBO.MPContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true; 
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true; 
    }      
}

AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;  // enables automatic migrations 
AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true; 
//this kinda gives permision to delete a table, what I mean is say you have a one to 
//many relation in a table and you decide to remove it for any reason by adding this 
//code you allow the migration to delete the reference (Sorry for the bad english) 

 public class TEST{

   public List<TEST2> test2 {get;set;}
  }
```

if you decide to remove test from test it deletes the reference from TEST class (thereore you lose that data)

P.S if you are using an online DB you might need to add `Persist Security Info=True` to your connection string

Hope this helps